# Replacing a string with another string using repl.bat

Tags: batch-file

Im replacing a string with another string in a html file using repl.bat

```
    set Source = "C:\input.html"
    set "Var1=CIT - Test – MIR3 Integration2"
    set "Var2 =CIT - Test – MIR3 Integration"
    type %Source% | repl "%Var1%" "%var2% M>output.html
```

This is not working here as the chatacter "–" in the variables is misinterpreted.

And this is working fine for simple text like var1 = apple, var2 = mango

Please help!

Comment: Not nececelery. You are setting variables named "Var1*space*" because batch is sensitive to spaces on **both** sides of the `=`. Furthermore, you are assigninging a value that contains quotes, then when you use them, you are re-quoting them.

Comment: when i echo var1, it shows like CIT - Test ΓÇô MIR3 Integration2 in cmd console.

Comment: i set as below and even this is not working.
    set "Var1= CIT - Test – MIR3 Integration2"
    set "Var2=CIT - Test – MIR3 Integration"

Comment: Please show us what the significant lines of data in `input.html` are.

Comment: @Magoo

<recipients>
<recipientSchedule>
Line21; CIT - Test – MIR3 Integration2
</recipientSchedule>
</recipients>
</broadcastInfo>

Line21: is written only for showing that that line number is 21.

Original html is like:
<recipients>
<recipientSchedule>
CIT - Test – MIR3 Integration
</recipientSchedule>
</recipients>
</broadcastInfo>

Comment: Please edit the lines into your question using `edit` below the tag-list.

Comment: REPL was deprecated over 2 years ago! http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044

Comment: Its not working even if i use JREPL.bat.